# proving existence of a function satisfying given conditions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $q$ be a mapping from the set of all closed intervals $[a, c] \in \mathbb{R}$ to real numbers that satisfies

(1) $q([a, c]) ≥ 0$ for all $a ≤ c$

(2) $q([a, c]) = q([a, b]) + q([b, c])$ for $a ≤ b ≤ c$

Prove that there exists a monotonically increasing function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that
$q([a, c]) = f(c) − f(a)$
for all $a ≤ c$

---

I haven't gotten very far. I know that if $f$ exists, then $f$ must be nondecreasing for (1) to be satisfied, and if $q([a, c]) = f(c) − f(a)$ then (2) is satisfied (since $q([a, c]) = f(c) − f(a) = f(c) - f(b) + f(b) - f(a) = q([a, b]) + q([b, c])$  -- however this isn't using that $b$ must be between $a$ and $c$)

I've covered up to the beginning of chapter 6 of Rudin's book (Riemann-Stieltjes integral) but I've never had to prove the existence of a function and not sure where to begin. I've done a bunch of googling around but haven't found any leads.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function $f$ by
$$f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto \begin{cases}q([0,x]) &x\geq 0\\-q([x,0])& x\leq 0\end{cases}. $$